# PHP Find all occurrences within radius of zip code

Tags: php, zip, maps

My boss just asked me to build a script that can pull all rows in a table that have a zipcode within a radius of a given zip code. I have never done anything like this before and I'm not sure where to start. Would this require interaction with Google maps or similar? What would be the best workflow, or some keywords to Google.

Comment: you might be able to use google maps by shifting the long/lat by a few degrees, but i feel like this would be tedious and inefficient. still not sure of the answer though... it is possible to use google maps to draw a radius around a specific point, although i'm not sure if you gather certain points and determine the zip code.

Comment: It depends on where you are!? US|UK|other. Very easy to do in certain countries, but radius is far harder than a square area (computationally). I've done it a few times, but you do need lat/long co-ords to make it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just did something just like this..these 2 resources are very helpful

PHP example of [Selecting points within a bounding circle](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html)

Full [database of all us zips and coordinates](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zips/)

Comment: Good answer, but make sure that given longer distances, that the 'great-circle' laws are applied.

Answer (score 0):

It is not something that will give you an immediate solution, but yes, you can use google maps. Free.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

You will need to, for the given zip, get geolocation, and then for the given radius, with step of every mile, check zip codes. That is what I would do. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure of how zipcodes works but i'm pretty confident that they have a similar number depending on its proximity, so maybe you could figure that out with a table instead of using something more complex, so lets say you make a query to search a range of zip codes between 33175 and 33188, i think the first thing to clarify is what kind of radius (2 miles,20 miles?) your boss want you to use so we can help you better, i hope this gives you an idea. 
Gl =)

Answer (score -1):

There exist "Zip code databases" in which you can find zip codes + latitude/longitude info about those zipcodes. Knowing latitude/longitude of one zip code, you can find other zipcodes located near it. This is example of such database info http://www.geopostcodes.com/sample.php?c=US This site (http://www.geopostcodes.com) sells these databases, but maybe you can find free version somewhere.

When you know latitude and longitude of "central" zipcode, you can find closest zipcodes using SQL like in this article http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/ but your table is not "members" but "zipcodes"